# How to Mouse Scroll Through Scene Selection?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

With *ctrl+scroll* you can quickly browse through values like *Area.type*.  How could you add this ctrl+mouse scroll-browse functionality to other drop-down menus to quickly select values for "scene" and "material"? 
[image: using ctrl+mouse scroll to move through properties windows]